# Prevent public access to MySQL port running using Docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm running MySQL using Docker-compose on my server.

This is the related part of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.27
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=app
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Now, it's accessible from the Internet ([Server Static IP]:3306) and it seems so insecure.

I want to **prevent** it from being accessible from the **Internet** and let it only be accessible **inside the server** and **through SSH**.

Comment: Imo, the host system should always have `iptables` or equivalent configured (`ufw` <3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify localhost (127.0.0.1) as the IP to bind (see the updated ports attributes).

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.27
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=app
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
```

I haven't tested this, but should work. As with anything security related, please do check yourself that it does work!

Comment: Found this is actually a duplicate question, plese vote to close :D